# Can I use a Global Variable for date/time?

Tags: datetime, globals

The goal is to create a global variable that allows the user to specify how they would like to format the date/time for entries. I'd like to remove the hardcoded format shown here:

```
{{ entry.postDate|date('Y.d.m') }}
```

And replace it with something like this:

```
{{ entry.postDate|date('{{ global__siteMetadata.gv__articleDateFormat }}') }}
```

The user would add "Y.d.m" or any other PHP date format they like through the global field in the CMS. But when I use this, I get the following output:

```
{{ 1THURSDAY2019PMTHURSDAY__001631AMERICA/CHICAGOMARAMERICA/CHICAGO31PM21PM31PM.1CT__PMTHU, 21 MAR 2019 13:16:00 -050031162019-03-21T13:16:00-05:00THURSDAYAMERICA/CHICAGOTHUPM31AMERICA/CHICAGOMARCH2019THU, 21 MAR 2019 13:16:00 -050003PM31 }}
```

Obviously, the global variable is not being parsed. Any thoughts on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You never need to nest Twig tags. It looks like `{{ glo...` is all being processed (or attempted to process) as PHP date shorthand codes.

Try this instead...

```
{{ entry.postDate|date(global__siteMetadata.gv__articleDateFormat) }}
```